# top 10 path reduction map reduce

Tags: hadoop, graph, mapreduce, bigdata, scalding

I am working on a project which needs path navigational graph.

Problem Description:
To give the project context, the sample UI is expected to look similar to: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570
.The difference is that it will be for site navigation. My problem is in dealing with data on the backend.

For user path A->B->C->D->E
The data format I precomputed looks like this:

```
Origin:Start:End:Level
A  A  B  L1
A  B  C  L2
A  C  D  L3
A  D  E  L4
```

Now, assume I have millions of records like this with 100's of Origins, I can group them, aggregate the size and sort by size desc and take the top 10. So for each origin, start and Level, I should have 10 records each.
So for a graph of 4 levels, I will have 10.. 10^2.. 10^3.. 10^4 for a given start node in graph.

The real problem:
The top 10 after sorting is not able to take away all not-required L3's and L4's. For a given origin the end of L1 should be the start of L2, the end of L2 should be the start of L3 and so on. Due to this reason I am having many records where many L2 starts do not belonging to L1 end and it multiplies as the level increase.
Illustration:

```
A  A  B  L1
A  B  C  L2
A  F  G  L2   <-- this comes in top 10 after aggregation, but start is not the end of L1 (B in this case)
```

What I tried: After sorting and slicing top 10, I do a self join for millions of records at each level 1 by 1. I have 10 levels. It is computationally really expensive.

What I am looking for:
Generic and less expensive Map-reduce solution. Better if I can get it in scalding context.

Answer (score 2):

Here I have a solution, but I am not sure it is suit for you:

I suppose what you want to do is take away all the not-required record which like :

A A B L1

A B C L2

A F G L2(not fit,take away,As there is no start from A to F through L2)

So when take away some not-required records, we must know whether the records are required or not;  I give the solution as follow:

First we must have a in memory data structure DB(which like Redis or Hazelcast); At the fist MapReduce we do nothing but insert data to the memory data structure DB; what we insert here is Map data(key is start:level  like A:L1 B:L5, and the value is a List which is the end)

So a Map maybe like this:

A:L1->B

A:L2->C G

After the first MapReduce we will know all the required record because we have the InMemoryDB;
And second MapReduce we take out the Records that not fit for;

We can jude a record like A F G L2  at mapper we query the Map in InMemoryDB like getList use the key A:L1(use this because we here at L2 started form A) is F in the List; If F is In the it is required, If not it is not;

Comment: thanks for taking time to understand. Thats exactly the problem actually. The second map reduce will do it for L2. I need to repeat the procedure for each consecutive level. L1 map filter L2. L2 map filter L3....upto 10 levels. This is expensive.